# Web Control Fileupload issue:

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I can't get the fileuploader to return if it is null or not.  if it is null I get a "path doesn't exist" error which is pointing to a local path and not my server path.

Anyone see this before?

```
 if (FileImgsave.HasFile)
    {
        string extensions = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileImgsave.FileName);

        if (extensions == ".jpg" || extensions == ".png" || extensions == ".gif" || extensions == ".jpeg")
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("/images/playerImages/");
            string ImageName = FileImgsave.FileName;
            FileImgsave.SaveAs(path + ImageName);
        }

    }
```

I( have tried so many different things and nothing worked...I basically was looking for to see if the fileuploader was null and if so then inject a name of a default image in its place.  while using a gender dropdownlist to decide what default image to use...but nothing worked unless I uploaded an image through the fileuploader.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This snippet works so the problem is not in there. PS you might want to call ToLower on the extenstion so it works with .JPG files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a relative or virtual path to map to a physical path.

If the parameter starts with / or \, it returns a path as if this parameter is a full virtual path.

If the parameter doesn't start with / or \, it returns a path relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed.

Also try using a relative path to return the relative physical path to the page that is being viewed in the browser :

```
Server.MapPath("../")
```

Or

```
Server.MapPath("..\")
```